# Specify template name for Html.EditorFor which takes List

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have multiple editor templates for my `PersonModel` object:

- `Views/Person/EditorTemplates/PersonModel.cshtml`
- `Views/Person/EditorTemplates/RestrictedPersonModel.cshtml`
- `Views/Person/EditorTemplates/NoImagePersonModel.cshtml`

As a test, these editor templates are identical:

```
@model MyApp.Models.PersonModel

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)
```

When using the following view:

```
@model List<MyApp.Models.PersonModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Basket";
}

<h1>All People</h1>

@if (Model.Count() > 0)
{
    <div>
       This is a list of all the people:
    </div>

    using (Html.BeginForm("SendID", "Person", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <div>

            @Html.EditorFor(model => model)

        </div>

        <div class="col-md-12">
            <button type="submit">
               Email IDs
            </button>
        </div>
    }
}
else
{
    <div>
        There are no people.
    </div>
}
```

the `Views/Person/EditorTemplates/PersonModel.cshtml` editor template is used, and the `List<PersonModel>` is passed through to the controller as required.

However, when I specify the template:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model, "RestrictedPersonModel")
```

I recieve the following error:

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyApp.Models.PersonModel]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'PrintRoom.Models.PersonModel'.
```

When replacing

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model, "RestrictedPersonModel")
```

with

```
@foreach (PersonModel p in Model)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(model => p, "RestrictedPersonModel")
}
```

then the `List<PersonModel>` is not passed through into my controller.

How can I specify the editor template to be used, and still receive the data in my controller?

Comment: I know this is an ancient question but I've just come across this same issue myself and it seems like a bug to me. What's the point in providing an overload that allows specifying a template name for the editor template if doing so changes the way it functions and requires extra code, thus reducing the benefit of using an editor template in the first place?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use a `for` loop rather than a `foreach` loop

```
for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
   @Html.EditorFor(m => m[i], "RestrictedPersonModel")
}
```

A `foreach` generates duplicate `name` attributes which have no relationship to your model (and duplicate `id` attributes which is invalid html)

Comment: This actually works, but it causes another problem - this collection will not be sent on posting the form. Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: @RomanBorovets. Yes it will. If it not working for you then its due to other issues with your code. You need to ask a new question showing the relevant code.